# wordpress acf pro gutenberg block отображение блоков в админке

Tags: wordpress, acf, gutenberg

У меня есть блок на сайте, слайдер. Который сделан через Swiper.js. Когда я добавляю его в гутенберг блок отображается блок в таком виде в админке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка на сайте:

[image: Картинка на сайте]

Можно ли как то сделать этот вид таким же как и в админке? То есть подключить к админке srcript.js файлы или же это никак не исправить и оно так и будет выглядеть?
Просто у меня нету понятия, так и должно быть или же я делаю не совсем правильные сайты в плане отображения и можно еще лучше это все реализовывать.

Comment: Поправить стили.

Comment: Так в стилях то все ок, это же через js задается остальные стили.
Можно ли как то js подключить к редактору или нет?)

Comment: Можно и js подключить (если вдруг не подключён, что вряд ли. Но если это так - плагин кривой). Но проще поправить стили. С которыми далеко не ОК, судя по скориншотам.

Comment: Вы наверное не поняли. В админке wordpress блок отображается без js, по этому и стили плывут. Потому что я не знаю как подключить js именно в Wordpress админку. что бы гутенберг блок отображался с js, а не только с css стилизацией.